# Cannot edit my TO-DO List web app using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Edit function in my code isn't working.
I tried a few different methods but ended up getting the same error.
The problem is with the edit function, but I can't figure it out. I am getting the error Uncaught TypeError: edit is not a function".

But I have defined the edit function. I tried adding this, but the edit gave me the same error.

The other functionalities like add and delete are working, but I am not able to edit my list of items. Please suggest a solution.

[JSFiddle Link to my code](https://jsfiddle.net/tc5bs2xa/)

This is my javascript code :

````
const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
const todoButton = document.querySelector(".todo-button");
const todoList = document.querySelector(".todo-list");
const filterOption = document.querySelector(".filter-todo");

//Event Listeners
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", getTodos);
todoButton.addEventListener("click", addTodo);
todoList.addEventListener("click", deleteTodo);
filterOption.addEventListener("click", filterTodo);

//Functions

function addTodo(e) {
  //Prevent natural behavior
  e.preventDefault();
  //Create todo div
  const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
  todoDiv.classList.add("todo");
  //Create list
  const newTodo = document.createElement("li");
  newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
  //Save to local - do this last
  //Save to local
  saveLocalTodos(todoInput.value);
  //
  newTodo.classList.add("todo-item");
  todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
  todoInput.value = "";

  var edit = document.createElement('button');
    edit.classList.add('edit');
      edit.innerHTML = "EDIT";
      edit.addEventListener('click', () => edit(e));
      todoDiv.appendChild(edit);

  //Create Completed Button
  const completedButton = document.createElement("button");
  completedButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-check"></i>`;
  completedButton.classList.add("complete-btn");
  todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
  //Create trash button
  const trashButton = document.createElement("button");
  trashButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>`;
  trashButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
  todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
  //attach final Todo
  todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);

  
}

function edit(e){
  const item = e.target;
  if(todoInput.disabled == true){
           todoInput.disabled = !todoInput.disabled;
        }
      else{
            todoInput.disabled = !todoInput.disabled;
            let indexof = todos.indexOf(item);
            todos[indexof] = todoInput.value;
            window.localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
        }
}

function deleteTodo(e) {
  const item = e.target;

  if (item.classList[0] === "trash-btn") {
    // e.target.parentElement.remove();
    const todo = item.parentElement;
    todo.classList.add("fall");
    //at the end
    removeLocalTodos(todo);
    todo.addEventListener("transitionend", e => {
      todo.remove();
    });
  }
  if (item.classList[0] === "complete-btn") {
    const todo = item.parentElement;
    todo.classList.toggle("completed");
    console.log(todo);
  }
}

function filterTodo(e) {
  const todos = todoList.childNodes;
  todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case "all":
        todo.style.display = "flex";
        break;
      case "completed":
        if (todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
        break;
      case "uncompleted":
        if (!todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
          todo.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
          todo.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
  });
}



function saveLocalTodos(todo) {
  let todos;
  if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
    todos = [];
  } else {
    todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
  }
  todos.push(todo);
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}
function removeLocalTodos(todo) {
  let todos;
  if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
    todos = [];
  } else {
    todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
  }
  const todoIndex = todo.children[0].innerText;
  todos.splice(todos.indexOf(todoIndex), 1);
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
}

function getTodos() {
  let todos;
  if (localStorage.getItem("todos") === null) {
    todos = [];
  } else {
    todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos"));
  }
  todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    //Create todo div
    const todoDiv = document.createElement("div");
    todoDiv.classList.add("todo");
    //Create list
    const newTodo = document.createElement("li");
    newTodo.innerText = todo;
    newTodo.classList.add("todo-item");
    todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
    todoInput.value = "";

    var edit = document.createElement('button');
    edit.classList.add('edit');
    edit.innerHTML = "EDIT";
    edit.addEventListener('click', () => edit(e));
    todoDiv.appendChild(edit);
    //Create Completed Button
    const completedButton = document.createElement("button");
    completedButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-check"></i>`;
    completedButton.classList.add("complete-btn");
    todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
    //Create trash button
    const trashButton = document.createElement("button");
    trashButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>`;
    trashButton.classList.add("trash-btn");
    todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
    //attach final Todo
    todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
  });
} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Try renaming the function to "OnEditPress".

You have a variable called "edit" as well as a function called "edit". Try using different names for these.

Comment: i have updated the code at https://jsfiddle.net/y504rmjp/ but the edit button is still not working and i am getting an error, Uncaught TypeError: todos.indexOf is not a function
    at onEditPress (app.js:62)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (app.js:157).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have renamed the method to onEditPress, don't forget to pass the event object to your renamed edit method

```
edit.addEventListener('click', (e) => onEditPress(e));
```

Comment: I have updated the code at jsfiddle.net/y504rmjp but the edit button is still not working and I am getting an error, Uncaught TypeError: todos.indexOf is not a function at onEditPress (app.js:62) at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (app.js:157).